# IllegalStateException: Call CookieSyncManager::createInstance() or create a webview before using this class

Tags: android, cookiemanager

I'm getting **ISE** when I call `CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url)`

```
I/dalvikvm( 1022): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Call CookieSyncManager::createInstance() or create a webview before using this class
I/dalvikvm( 1022):     at android.webkit.JniUtil.checkInitialized(JniUtil.java:45)
I/dalvikvm( 1022):     at android.webkit.JniUtil.getDatabaseDirectory(JniUtil.java:66)
I/dalvikvm( 1022):     at android.webkit.CookieManager.nativeGetCookie(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm( 1022):     at android.webkit.CookieManager.getCookie(CookieManager.java:496)
I/dalvikvm( 1022):     at android.webkit.CookieManager.getCookie(CookieManager.java:460)
```

Could anyone please point me out why it happens and how to resolve it?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Did you follow the advice in the exception message?

Comment: yes, I eventually resolved the issue by following that prompt.